# Postman test case insetitive

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a test case in the Postman which looks like:

```
pm.test("Last Name contains Bob", () => {
    const responseJson = pm.response.json();
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    pm.response.json().result.length >= 1;
    pm.expect(responseJson.result[0].last_name).to.include.a("Bob");
});
```

but that fail for a result which has BOBBY as `last_name`

I thought that by adding `a` to the assertion it will became case insensitive.

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Postman uses the Chai assertion library, that's not how `a` works. https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_a you could use `match` and use regex for case insensitive maybe?

Comment: @DannyDainton Youp, `match` with proper regex works. Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth adding your solution and accept that as the answer so that folks visiting here can see it too. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for my case wast to use `match` with Regex

```
pm.test("Last Name contains Bob", () => {
    const responseJson = pm.response.json();
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    pm.response.json().result.length >= 1;
    pm.expect(responseJson.result[0].last_name).to.match(\Bob\gmi);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
        pm.expect(someprop.toLowerCase()).to.include("<some_lower_case_string>");
```